# Should the footnote be capitalized?

Tags: capitalization, writing-style, footnotes

If we refer a textual content in a footnote, should it be capitalized or not?

Here is an example:

> The proposed method is only working well with homogeneous space and it fails if the space is heterogeneous<sup>1</sup>.

Then for the *heterogeneous* we have a footnote which is :

> <sup>1</sup>  Which is the case for the ambiguous queries.

So, should it be *which* or *Which* in the footnote?

Comment: Please give an example; the use of *refer* in the question is not very clear. Generally, normal rules for capitalisation apply everywhere, but perhaps you have found an interesting edge-case.

Comment: @AndrewLeach edited. please have a look. Since we are talking about capitalizing, I was wondering if for word(s)in a quotation or a double quotation should be capitalized or not? thanks :)

Comment: We have questions already about quotations. (I've tidied the edit a little: code quoting is not used in ELU.)

Comment: @AndrewLeach I got used to the other forums of this kind so I added code like that. Thanks anyhow though I am still confused for the footnote thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most extensive discussion of footnote capitalization that I've found is in *Words Into Type*, third edition (1974):

> **Capitalization.** Footnotes ordinarily begin with a capital and end with a period, but occasionally, in a book in which capitals are used sparingly, footnotes may begin with a lowercase letter.
>
> [Examples:]
>
> > <sup>1</sup> p. 63
> >
> > <sup>2</sup> op. cit.
> >
> > <sup>3</sup> ch. 9
>
> The nature of the notes may make lowercase more logical and appropriate, as in the following from *Nineteenth-Century Spanish Plays*:
>
> > <sup>1</sup> *por la posta*, "in all haste"
> >
> > <sup>2</sup> *ab intestato*, "intestate," "without having made a will"

Obviously this is only the recommendation of a single style guide, though *Words Into Type* is widely used in U.S. publishing houses as a style reference. The quoted advice suggests that, if a footnote consists of a phrase or sentence fragment, you need not capitalize it or end it with a period (or any other end punctuation). So in your case, the footnote could look like this:

> <sup>1</sup> which is the case for the ambiguous queries

I get the sense that, if you preferred to open the footnote with a capital letter and to end it with a period, *Words Into Type* would endorse framing the footnote as a complete sentence:

> <sup>1</sup> This is the case for the ambiguous queries.

And of course you always have the option of presenting the footnoted content as a parenthetical aside in the running text:

> The proposed method is only working well with homogeneous space and it fails if the space is heterogeneous (which is the case for the ambiguous queries).

Comment: Looks nice. Now I can die in peace.

Answer (score 5):

I have no sources for this, but it should either

- be capitalized, in which case the footnote is an **incomplete sentence**, because the subject (the word that *Which* refers to) is missing

  (In this case, the footnote number in the main sentence should come after the period:
  “*[…] heterogeneous.<sup>1</sup>*”, because the footnote is a sentence of its own, and having a full sentence within another full sentence makes no sense.),

or,

- be left uncapitalized, in which case the footnote is a **relative clause**, where *which* is referring to the word *heterogeneous* in the referred-to independent clause.

  Note that in this case the trailing period in the footnote must be removed as well, since the main clause (the non-footnote one) already contains the period.

Comment: Who says? Where's your evidence that this is more than your opinion?

Comment: I'm on this with @curiousdannii . Prove your point.

Comment: Although you did  not prove your point, but the answer that Sven Yargs gave to my question is somehow similar to your idea, so I upvote your answer.

Comment: And _I_ find its internal logic is entirely sufficient to make this answer stand correct by itself. Sometimes language makes enough sense by itself that it doesn't require arbitrary conventions for people to agree on matters, and this looks to me like on of those cases.